# setting a different background in materialdesign's popup box control

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design

I can only either change the background to Light/Dark with changing the BaseTheme property in App.xaml. Is there a way to change the background to a different color? Setting the background property on the control it self doesn't seem to do anything.